# Non-negative constraint using PyDSTool -- not working

Tags: python

I recently found PyDSTool while searching for something that could solve a system of ODEs and obey constraints (all I need for my graphs is that the values stay above 0 since they are modelling populations). Although the documentation is rather poor, basic usage has not been that difficult, but I am coming into some trouble adding in that non-negativity constraint.

It is as if the **xdomain** line  is just being completely ignored. The code below produces a plot that crosses the x-axis, so I must be doing something wrong in setting up the bounds. Does anybody have any advice?

```
import PyDSTool as pdt

ini = {'A':1000,'B':1000,'C':1000}
DSargs = pdt.args(name='test',
                  ics=ini,
                  tdata = [0,20],
                  varspecs = {'A':'-100','B':'0','C':'1'},
                  xdomain = {'A':[0,pdt.Inf],'B':[0,pdt.Inf],'C':[0,pdt.Inf],'incontact':1})
DS = pdt.Generator.Vode_ODEsystem(DSargs)
traj = DS.compute('test')
pts = traj.sample()


pdt.plt.plot(pts['t'],pts['A'],label='A')
pdt.plt.plot(pts['t'],pts['B'],label='B')
pdt.plt.plot(pts['t'],pts['C'],label='C')
pdt.plt.legend()
pdt.plt.xlabel('t')
pdt.plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you reformat your question along [ask]?