# PyDSTool: Non Negative constraint (using xdomain) does not work

Tags: python, constraints, modeling, ode, differential-equations

I am using PyDSTool to create an 'SIRV' model. For this model, none of the variables 'S', 'I', 'R', or 'V' can go below 0 or go above a predefined value (known as 'N'). I have seen that PyDSTool has a built in function 'xdomain' which claims to be able to implement these restrictions. However, much like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662464/non-negative-constraint-using-pydstool-not-working), it does not work. Although the code runs, its as if its being treated like its not there. I have attached my relevant code:

```
#---Import---#
import PyDSTool as dst
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#---SIRV Code---#
icdict = {'s': 0.999, 'i': 0.001, 'r': 0, 'v': 0} 
pardict = {'beta': 2.4/14, 'D': 14, 'L': 5, 'N': 1, 'rho': 0}

ds_rhs = '-beta * (i/N) * s - rho'
di_rhs = 'beta * (i/N) * s - ((1/D) * i)'
dr_rhs = '(1/D) * i'
dv_rhs = 'rho'

vardict = {'s': ds_rhs, 'i': di_rhs, 'r': dr_rhs, 'v': dv_rhs} 

DSargs = dst.args() 
DSargs.name = 'SIRV'
DSargs.ics = icdict 
DSargs.pars = pardict
DSargs.tdata = [0, 20] 
DSargs.varspecs = vardict
#DSargs.xdomain = {'s': [0,5000000], 'i': [0,5000000], 'r': [0,5000000], 'v': [0,5000000]}

DS = dst.Generator.Vode_ODEsystem(DSargs)

DS.set(pars={'beta': 5/14, 'N': 5000000, 'rho': 9000},
       ics={'s': 4999999, 'i': 1},
       xdomain = {'s': [0,5000000], 'i': [0,5000000], 'r': [0,5000000], 'v': [0,5000000]}, #has no effect
       tdata = [0, 400])

traj = DS.compute('demo')
pts = traj.sample()

#---Plotting---#
plt.plot(pts['t'], pts['s'], label='S')
plt.plot(pts['t'], pts['i'], label='I')
plt.plot(pts['t'], pts['r'], label='R')
plt.plot(pts['t'], pts['v'], label='V')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.show()
```

Comment: With the term `- rho` in the first equation the exact solution can go negative for `s`. Check your source if you should replace `rho` with `rho*s` in both places.

Comment: The issue with doing that is that as s gets smaller, the effect rho has also gets smaller. I want the effect rho has to stay constant, hence trying to use the xdomain function.

Comment: But the effect relative to the size of `s` stays constant. In your version, it is possible for a while to remove a constant 10 per cycle if you start with 1000, but inevitably you reach the value 0, and then you should not be able to take away another 10 if we speak of populations or their densities. However, removing 1% per cycle is possible without limit, even if the numbers considered become ludicrously small.

Comment: Apologies, I worded my comment wrong. What I mean is that I want rho to remove 9000 from s no matter the size of s, but once s reaches or goes below 0, it should stay at 0. From what I read online, I had thought that xdomain could achieve this.